# Using Apple Configurator 2, Prepare iOS Device Without Updating iOS

Tags: apple-ios, mdm

I essentially have an updated version of this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151020/30844

I have an iOS 9.0.2 device. I want to Prepare and Supervise it with Configurator 2 (Apple's new OS X - iOS mobile device management tool), but do not want to update the device to iOS 9.1. With the old Configurator, this was possible (see answer to linked question).

Does anyone know if there is a similar way to do this with the new Configurator 2?

Comment: Crossposted [here 6 days ago ... no response yet](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/215480/30844)

Comment: Did you get any answer for that ??
Still looking for a way to switch a iOS 8.4 into supervised mode and keeping it into iOS8... not 9 !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way Apple wants you to do this is [described here](http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.0/#/cad789a3f0bd):

> **Update iOS beta software** 
>   You can use Apple Configurator 2 to install beta versions of iOS software.
>
> - To install iOS beta software on a device, select the device in the    device browser and drag the .ipsw file onto the device.

[image]

However, the specific use case described is for *beta* versions of iOS. In my case, I wanted to install an *older* (than the newest public) version of iOS. It looks like the UI is the same for doing either.

When I attempted to prepare my device this way, the process failed with error codes:

> Personalization failed: 4027 
>  
>   Personalization failed: 3194

I am not clear whether this is because updating a device to less than the newest version is unsupported ... or there is some other problem. Therefore, I'm leaving this answer, but not accepting it as solved, should someone else have more to add.